# Selecting rows on the basis of other matrix and calculate mean of every selected row

Tags: r

I want to calculate average stock returns for each period based on some ranking of stocks. For this purpose I have two matrix. First matrix will be used to calculate ranks of the stocks. On the basis of the ranks of the stocks. I will select stocks from matrix2. Number of stocks will vary from row to row. For example in first row it may be 32, for second it may be 33. Second matrix represent returns for stocks. After it we will select that 32 stocks and calculate average return. Similar for next rows. I have try to make a reproducible example. Please see it if you need any clarity please comment.

```
matrix1<-as.matrix(data.frame(a=c(13,21,7,6),b=c(10,13,2,9),c=c(14,20,19,18)))
rank<-apply(-matrix1,1,rank)                
RankRB <- function(x){

   r <- as.matrix(t(apply(-x, 1, rank, na.last = "keep")))
  return(r)
}
Rank<-RankRB(matrix1)
matrix2<-as.matrix(data.frame(a=c(0.5,0.4,0.2,0.1),b=c(0.3,0.2,0.2,0.1),c=c(0.25,0.20,0.30,0.40)))
top_n<-c(2,1,1,2)
Required_output<-c(0.375,0.40,0.30,0.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
rank <- t(rank)
sapply(seq_along(top_n), function(x) 
                  mean(matrix2[x, ][which(rank[x, ] %in% 1:top_n[x])]))
#[1] 0.375 0.400 0.300 0.250
```